# Sequel eager load some associations of single ORM object

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am building the data model for a small application, and would like to take advantage of eager loading in some methods - i.e. those where I know in advance that certain associations are going to get used.

I have read [the Sequel::Model::Association](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/Associations/DatasetMethods.html) guide to the `.eager` method, but it has confused me a little. A typical example might be:

```
Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks ).all
```

which loads all the Artist objects with all their albums fields preloaded, and all the tracks pre-loaded, using just three queries. So far, so good.

But say I want to load a single Artist by its primary key, and still have the albums + tracks pre-loaded (still three queries, potentially a lot less than following the associations for each album)? I cannot see any example of that. A little experimentation gives me

```
Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks ).where( :id => id ).all.first
```

which seems to at least work. I confirmed the eager loading by calling this, then switching off the db, and showing I could still access the associations.

However, I feel like I have missed something. The construct, having to pass in the primary key to the `where` clause, get a full dataset then ask for first item seems quite awkward. I am looking for something like this:

```
Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks )[ id ]
```

. . . a simple way of declaring I want to load a single object, and eager load some of its associations.

I *have* found that I can create a custom association like this:

```
def eager_albums
  albums_dataset.eager( :tracks ).all
end
```

but that is awkward to use, because the code has to ask for the association in a different way.

My question: Does my construct `Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks ).where( :id => id ).all.first` do what I *think* it does in Sequel, and could I do better (simpler code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks ).where( :id => id ).all.first` fetches all artists with an id equal to 'id' and then extracts the first artist from the result array (calling `all` materializes the array). Typically this query will only be returning an array with a single artist.

It is not until you actually ask for the relationship `artist.albums` or associations beyond the album that additional queries are run.

You could just do `Artist.eager( :albums => :tracks ).where( :id => id ).first`

I use the [tactical eager loading plugin](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/TacticalEagerLoading.html) so its pretty much unnecessary to use eager at all since it detects when an association is being used from an model instance which is part of a larger result set and does the eager load of related models for the entire result set automatically. Your query now becomes `Artist[id]`, or `Artist[id].albums.all`

Another handy plugin I use is the [association proxies plugin](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/AssociationProxies.html) so I don't have to deal with using `association.some_array_method` vs `association_dataset.some_ds_method`

And finally the [dataset associations plugin](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/DatasetAssociations.html) allows you to describe a query starting from some model or model class and chain through associations to a destination model whilst allowing you to define constraints (or not) along the way.

For example "find all tracks longer than 3 minutes on any album released in the past 2 weeks by artists born in the UK":

`Artist.where(country_of_birth: 'UK').albums.where{ release_date > Date.today - 14}.tracks.where{ duration > 3.minutes }.all`

Hope this sheds some light.

Comment: Useful information, thank you but I am not certain "It is not until you actually ask for the relationship artist.albums or associations beyond the album that additional queries are run." is true for my query - I have run my query *switched off the db server* and then iterated through the child objects in the relationships in Ruby successfully (admittedly that was around the time I asked the question, things may have changed, or my test may have had flaws).

Comment: Out of the box eager() definitely does not execute related association queries until you ask for them. eager_graph() is a different beast and has the behaviour you describe. You may have had the association cached from a previous query or some other side-effect referencing the associations and triggering the load. Unless you call artist.albums(true) an association will be cached and won't reload, see: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html#label-Caching